# Problemas ao receber dinheiro como input no edittext

Tags: android, edittext

Estou construindo um app em Android Studio que recebe um valor inserido em um `edittext`, passa ele para `BigDecimal` e realiza algumas operações.

No campo para inserir esse valor, marquei `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`, porém, o teclado não está inserindo "." Ou "," de forma alguma, e isso me impede de receber os centavos desse valor.

O que eu **realmente** preciso era um campo com máscara que por padrão exibisse **R$ 0.00** e a pessoa só inserisse os números, mas se eu conseguir simplesmente receber o separador entre valor inteiro e centavos já me atenderia.

Comment: Poderia postar seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Eu encontrei uma solução no [github](https://github.com/faranjit/currency_edittext).

```
<faranjit.currency.edittext.CurrencyEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_currency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:groupDivider="."
        app:monetaryDivider=","
        app:locale="en_US"
        app:showSymbol="true" />
```

E para obter os valores:

```
double d = currencyEditText.getCurrencyDouble();
String s = currencyEditText.getCurrencyText();
```

Comment: Olá eliangela, tentei a sua solução, mas não adiantou, quando clico no ponto, ele não aparece no edittext, e eu também não recebo ele, aí não consigo separar as vírgulas. Obg mesmo assim

Answer (score 0):

Defina o EditText no XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="double" />
```

E no Java use um **NumberFormat**

```
public class Minha Activity extends Activity {

    private NumberFormat f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {

        f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        f.setMaximmumFractionDigits(2);
        f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    }

}
```

E é só ir no EditText e fazer:

```
f.format(valorAqui);
```

Que no seu caso vai ser mais ou menos assim:

```
f.format(String.valueOf(edt.getText().toString()));
```

*Não esqueça de importar o NumberFormat. (java.text.NumberFormat)*.

Comment: Oi António, o problema é que não existe esse inputType, só number, numberDecimal e uns outros que não servem. O problema é que quando eu clico no ponto no teclado, ele não é adicionado ao valor, e aí não tem como ter um valor com centavos